# how treat exception in django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, try-catch

I have a model with a attribute with *'Unique=True* this attribute refers a model that is responsible for evaluate a candidates, a Evaluator can evaluate just one candidate. So when I try evaluate a candidate with the same evaluator the Django return the *ValueError*, so I tried treat exception, but it don't work...Exist a special way to treat exception in Django?

**views.py(is in *def evaluation* ):**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidate, Criterion, Evaluation
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import EvalForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def canditate_list(request):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all()

    eva = Evaluation.objects.all()
    eval_cand_list = []                                     #aqui guarda uma lista com os FK candidates convertidos p/ str

    context = {
        'candidates': candidates,
        'eva': eva
    }
    return render(request, 'app/candidate_list.html',context)

def candidate_detail(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    c_name = candidate.name                                 #pega o nome (string) do candidato
    c1 = Evaluation.objects.all()                           #guarda tds Evaluation na variavel  
    scores = []                                             #declara a array que vai receber as notas
    for c in c1:                                            
        cand = str(c.candidate)                             #guarda o nome do candidato do Evaluation atual
        if cand == c_name:                                  #confere se o Evaluation atual corresponde ao candidate atual(pk)
            scores += [c.score]

    _sum = 0                                                #variavel que guardara a soma declarada
    for s in scores:
        _sum += s                                           #faz a soma dos scores

    average = 0 
    if len(scores) > 0:
        average = _sum/len(scores)                              #tira a média

    context = {
        'candidate': candidate,
        'average': average
    }

    return render(request, 'app/candidate_detail.html', context)

def evaluation(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
                if form2.is_valid():    
                    post = form2.save(commit=False)
                    post.save()
                    return redirect('canditate_list') 
            except ValueError:
                return('Você já avaliou este candidato!')
        else:
            try:
                form2 = EvalForm()
                return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})
            except ValueError:
                return('Você já avaliou este candidato!')

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidate_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Criterion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    higher_education = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    average = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    #############################################################score = models.ForeignKey()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Evaluation(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, unique=True)
    criterion = models.ForeignKey(Criterion, default='')
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    appraiser = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidate)
```

[EDIT]:

the error returned is:

> ValueError: The view app.views.evaluation didn't return an
>   HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: What is the specific error:

` except ValueError as e: print(e)`

Comment: why 'print(e)' I can't use return() here? I try do this but no result

Comment: The content of the ValidationError might help debugging, if not print, log

Comment: Don't is a ValidationError dude, is a ValueError...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is not due to not handling `ValueError` but due to not returning a HTTP response back to the client. The error is quite explicit:

```
ValueError: The view app.views.evaluation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

First of all, the exception that is raised when you're trying to save an entry to database with a `unique = True` contraint is [`IntegrityError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError).

Change your `evaluation` view to this:

```
# views.py

from django.db import IntegrityError

def evaluation(request):
    # form2 initialization
    form2 = EvalForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():    
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            try:
                post.save()  # if candidate exists, then IntegrityError will be raised
            except IntegrityError:
                # Handle error here. Maybe add a message or something
                # and pass it though the context
    # if its a GET method, form2 will be unbound (ready to filled with data)
    # if its a POST method, form2 will be filled with any potential errors
    return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})
```

Comment: Thanks man, you solve my problem...but I have another question hehe,first: After the 'except IntegrityError:' I put return("message here") but when I try to add a existent candidate the def don't return what I command(I try with 'return HttpReponse()' to), his return the django pattern message error: "Evaluation with this Candidate already exists.", you know where I can alter this message and change to a personalized message? Second: How you know that is a IntegrityError instead a ValueError, being that the error message just quoted only ValueError, you debugging the code or just knew?

Comment: Every time there is a constraint violence, an `IntegrityError` is raised by Django. `IntegrityError` is a subclass of `DatabaseError`. I just know it. Now for the other part of your question, inside the `except` clause, you should add `return HttpResponse('Your message here')` or better `return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2, message: 'Your message here'})` and inside `evaluation.html` access message as `{{ message }}`.

Comment: I get it! Thanks for the attention dude!